# reset elements for media queries

Tags: html, css

Can anyone suggest a way to undo the display property?

I have three divs which I gave the value; display: inline-flex; so that they would appear horizontally. When creating my media queries, I want to remove this so that they will appear vertically. I thought display: initial; would work but no luck. neither does targeting the divs individually with display: block;

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to provide more information, ideally in a functioning snippet.

Comment: Please provide some code so we can help.

Comment: Kindly provide the code so we can help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the code that you used but still I understand the issue.
You are using `display: inline-flex;` on the three divs, inline flex is a property used for **div containers** and it will align all the divs inline.

a simple solution I would suggest is that you wrap a container around those divs and give the container the property of `display: flex`

here is the **HTMl**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

here is the **CSS**

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
#div1,#div2,#div3{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .container{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

also, here is a link so you can see it in action, resize the screen to see the media query in effect https://codepen.io/codebyrudra/pen/NWvyVzd

Comment: Thank you Rudy, that worked. I've been pulling my hair out most of the day with this.

Comment: It was my pleasure :)